# Can I pass an argument to the slot function when using QObject::connect?

Tags: qt

Qt4.8.5

```
 QObject::connect(button,SIGNAL(clicked()),label,SLOT(setText("dd"));
```

The Qt Creator tell me It's wrong . What's the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That you can't pass arguments in a `connect()` statement. You need a "trampoline" slot that sets the text of your label (or, in Qt 5, you might choose to use a lambda).

For instance, by using a subclass:

```
class MyLabel : public QLabel {
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void setTextToFoo() { setText("foo"); }
};
// ...
connect(button,SIGNAL(clicked()),label,SLOT(setTextToFoo());
```

Comment: class MyLabel : public QLabel {
    Q_OBJECT

public slots:
    void setTextToFoo() { setText("foo"); }
};
  MyLabel *ll;

Comment: Sorry I'm a beginner.I'm learning and I don't know how to inherit from QLabel and use it for now.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what exactly you are trying to achieve, to be honest, the example code you provided is not very functional, is "dd" a particular static value you are using, or potentially some other string? Where does it come from, is it in the scope of the called, or is it sent by the caller, which is the usual practice when sending arguments to slots.

Either way, in order to make a connect statement the first requirement is for the arguments to match, `clicked()` has no arguments while `setText()` has one, so there is a mismatch. As of how to resolve that mismatch, the easiest way is to use simple wrappers, although you can use a `QSignalMapper` and as of Qt5, lambdas and std::bind.

For starters, you cannot specify the actual argument instance in the connect statement, even with arguments on both sides you only need to specify the types to help resolve overloads (it is terrible with the new connection syntax in Qt5), and not any actual identifiers or literals.

In case of the more usual scenario, where the data is send to the slot by the caller, the identifier or literal is specified in the `emit signal(value)` statement. Since you don't have `clicked(const QString &)` you need a wrapper slot that you connect to `clicked()` and emit with the value in that wrapper slot, or subclass the button and add your own overload of `clicked(QString)`.

In case the value is in the scope of the called, then  subclassing doesn't make much sense, all you need is the wrapper slot in the scope of the called object.

If you want more, you will have to use Qt 5, whose syntax is significantly more powerful.

Comment: Yeah the code he posted isn't functional, yet this is about how it works in boost. In boost, you could probably do something like: `button.clickSignal.connect(boost::bind(&QLabel::setText, label, "dd"))`. Boost allows you to define parameters by literal values.

Comment: @TomášZato - `std::bind()` has been a part of C++ for like 5 years now.

Comment: I never said it was not, but your answer only mentions it, does not explain what to do with it. That's why I posted the comment that explains what I would expect using syntax I know.

Comment: @TomášZato - well thank god you did, because it is not like there are already a ton of answers explaining that ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the question is whats wrong, just remember the parameter number must be the same for the Signal and the Slot. Asking a collegue and according the Peppe, setText(QString) wait for One parameter and the Clicked() is empty...A custom slot is to call the setText() method indirectly.

You can look that : http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-calculator.html
It uses the QWidget, an important part of Qt interfaces beside QML.